# Regex - To allow numeric, only characters R, N, X, B, @

Tags: javascript, regex

---

Hi,
Can somebody help me with the regex that allow all numeric, and only characters R, N, X, B
and special characters like @ or $.

Thanks,
Ruth

Comment: did you try doing some research before asking?

Comment: this is the most basic regex, if you want to use regex, you should be able to handle this question.

Comment: @leonhart thus, my downvote for the lack of research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the token `[\dRNXB@$]`. Add to the ending `+` if you need it to match 1 or more times or a `*` if you need it to match 0 or more times.

`\d` is special and matches any digit character. Make sure that if you're in a context where backslashes are being used for escape sequences (such as in a string) that you double the backslash.

http://regular-expressions.info/reference.html for more information